# Product of a divergent limit and a convergent limit approaching infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I am studying convergent and divergent series and therefore have to review some limits. While doing a practice problem I encountered the follwoing problem:

$$\lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {{(-1)}^{n}\sqrt{n+1}}{n}$$

In this case, the ${(-1)^n}$ diverges according to [*Symbolab*](https://es.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(-1%5Cright)%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cright)?or=input). However, the other bit converges to $0$.

$$\lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty }\frac {\sqrt{n+1}}{n} = \lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty }\sqrt {\frac {{n+1}}{n^2}}=\lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty }\sqrt {\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}=0$$

My assumption is that if we were to split the first part of the equation into two options we could say ${-1}^n$ is either negative or positive depending if $n$ is odd or even. In any case, we would still be multiplying by $0$ making the limit of the whole function $0$.

Is my line of thought wrong? And if so, why cannot I analyze the function that way?

My guess would be that I am treating $\infty$ like a number so my analysis would be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine since $a_n=\frac {\sqrt{n+1}}{n} \to 0$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$ is bounded by $|b_n|\le M=1$ it is a general result that by squeeze therorem

$$\left|a_n \cdot b_n \right|\le |a_n|M \to0 \cdot M =0 \implies a_n \cdot b_n \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $0$, because, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$-\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n\leqslant\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}n\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n$$and therefore, by the squeeze theorem, and since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n=0,$$the limit of your sequence is $0$.

Concerning your first approach, I don't know what you are talking about when you mention “we cannot multiply a number by $\infty$”. There is no multiplication by $\infty$ here.

Comment: I was thinking about another problem and wrote that on accident. Disregard that part.

Comment: In other words, my analysis was correct. You just took the function and saw the two cases of $n$ odd/even.

Comment: No, it is not. The simple fact that $(-1)^n$ is negative or positive is not enough. If you had $(-n)^n$ instead, your sequence would actually diverge.